# Color depth is loosing when I convert System.Drawing.Icon to byte[]

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a logic

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    icon.ToBitmap();
    var array = ms.GetBuffer();
}
```

and

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(array))
{
    var icon = new Icon(ms);
}
```

I expect to get a source icon, but I get an icon with wrong colors.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxB5x.png)

How can i fix it?

UPD
i have 2 methods

```
    public static byte[] ToByteArray(this Icon icon)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            icon.Save(ms);
            return ms.GetBuffer();
        }
    }

    public static Icon ToIcon(byte[] bytes)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            return new Icon(ms);
        }
    }
```

Ps 
**MemoryStream.ToArray()** does not work correctly too.
**icon.ToBitmap()** returns a black background

UPD2:

```
    public static void Func()
    {
        Icon icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon("filename");
        var iconBytes = icon.ToByteArray();
        //...... SOME LOGIC.......
        var restoredIcon = ToIcon(iconBytes);
        image.Source = restoredIcon.ToImageSource();
    }
    public static byte[] ToByteArray(this Icon icon)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            icon.Save(ms);
            return ms.GetBuffer();
        }
    }

    public static Icon ToIcon(byte[] bytes)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            return new Icon(ms);
        }
    }

    public static ImageSource ToImageSource(this Icon icon)
    {
        ImageSource imageSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
            icon.Handle,
            Int32Rect.Empty,
            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        return imageSource;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `MemoryStream.ToArray()` to get the bytes? Also, does `icon.ToBitmap()` return a value or does it alter the object itself?

Comment: How do you expect `icon.ToBitmap()` to write data to the memory stream? You're not passing in `ms` anywhere. My guess is that this isn't your real code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This still isn't a [mcve], although I note that your `ToByteArray` method looks very different from your first snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Icon.ToBitmap loses transparency per this documentation:

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.drawing.icon.tobitmap(v=vs.100).aspx/html
```

The transparent areas of the icon are lost when it is converted to a bitmap, and the transparent color of the resulting bitmap is set to RGB(13,11,12). The returned bitmap has the same height and width as the original icon.

Try this, assuming that color isn't present in the image, after the ToBitmap(), you can call a statement to make that color transparent:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap img = icon.ToBitmap();
img.MakeTransparent(Color.FromArgb(13, 11, 12));
```

Comment: Close. I edited my code to `using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buff))
            {
                bmpNew = new Bitmap(ms);
                bmpNew.MakeTransparent(Color.Black);
            }`. And it works now.